# Disable jquery validate on submit, but still run invalidHandler and submitHandler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form containing a dynamic (user-created) amount of input fields, some of which need to be validated. The amount of input fields can very likely get into the tens of thousands, and so when I click submit, if there is a large number of fields created, **jquery validate freezes up my browser for several seconds while it checks and marks my input fields as invalid**.

This is bad and unnecessary since **I'm already marking my input fields upon creation** and on keyup, and then I have `invalidHandler` take care of alerting the user and then I do a bunch of stuff with my inputs in `submitHandler`.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    onsubmit: false,
    onkeyup: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        //alert user, highlight invalid fields...
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        //a bunch of stuff...
    }
});
```

But when I try that and I click submit, the form straight up gets submitted, even if it has invalid fields, passing straight through both my handlers. I get it that it's because I'm not validating on submit, but I assumed that setting  `onsubmit: false` would simply prevent the plugin from **unnecessarily re-checking and re-marking already marked inputs**, while still running my handlers. How do I achieve this?

Comment: IF you are already doing validation, why are using using the validate plugin?

Comment: For setting the rules for validation, for checking if fields are valid on keyup and preventing the user from sending invalid forms. For every reason except *checking* the validity of the form before submitting, since the validity is already being checked in other events.

Comment: So write that portion? `$("#myForm").on("submit", function(event){ if ($(this).find(".error").length){ event.preventDefault(); }});`

Comment: `onsubmit: false` is causing that.  It means that validation will NOT happen when you click the `submit` button.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear.  You want to use this plugin and yet you don't want it to do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: *"For every reason except checking the validity of the form before submitting"* <- that right there is exactly what this plugin is ***designed*** to do, check the form before submission.  I suggest you write your own validation instead of using this plugin.

Comment: Yes, I still want the plugin to prevent the submit action, but the problem is that before preventing it, the plugin **re-checks** every single one of my tens of thousands of inputs to see if they're valid, causing my browser to freeze, and that is what I don't want to happen, since I already check every input when it's initialized.

Comment: You are nit-picking how the plugin was designed in order to use it in a case that is highly abnormal.... *"tens of thousands"* of inputs?  Really?  I suggest you write your own JavaScript for this, although I think no matter how you write it, it's going to choke on a form that large.

Comment: Maybe I am nit-picking. It's unlikely that people will have forms this big, but still, doesn't it make sense to not check the validity of fields on submit if they are already being initialized as invalid? Even if in most situations it would only be a small boost in performance, in other cases, such as this, it's huge.

Comment: If you're nit-picking plugin performance, then that's not something Stack Overflow can address.  Take your complaint to the developer's GitHub page.

Comment: I think if it was another situation where performance was barely affected it would be nit-picking. But in my situation the performance hit can get into the minutes for something that is not necessary every time. Also this plugin attended every one of my needs until this point and re-doing everything I did using this plugin just so I could control something trivial like "not checking validity on submit" would be a huge undertaking. I would rather put up a "plase wait" message in this case. If the plugin doesn't already allow for that, which seems to be the case, I'll open an issue on Github.